# Generating random date in a specific range in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, date

How to generate random dates in a specific range in JAVA? I have seen [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range) link which is to generate random numbers.Is there similar/other kind of way to generate random date in JAVA?

Comment: Just create a date from a random timestamp.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given that your question is unclear, I am expecting you are trying to generate random `java.util.Date` with given range.

Please note that `java.util.Date` contains date + time information.

`Date` in Java is represented by milliseconds from EPOCH.  Therefore the easiest way to do what you want is, given d1 and d2 is `Date`, and d1 < d2 (in pseudo-code):

```
Date randomDate = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                              .nextLong(d1.getTime(), d2.getTime()));
```

---

If it is actually a "Date" (without time) that you want to produce, which is usually represented by `LocalDate` (in Java 8+, or using JODA Time).

It is as easy as, assume d1 and d2 being `LocalDate`, with `d1 < d2` (pseudo-code):

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(d1, d2).toDays();
LocalDate randomDate = d1.addDays(
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(days+1));
```

Comment: In Java 8, you must first get an instance of ThreadLocalRandom to call nextLong method.

**ThreadLocalRandom.current()**

Example would be like this: 
`Date randomDate = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(d1.getTime(), d2.getTime()));`

Comment: @ImtiazShakilSiddique thanks for spotting the mistake.  It is actually the case even before JDK8.  Lemme fix it

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(1990, 1, 1); //start date
    long start = startDate.toEpochDay();
    System.out.println(start);

    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now(); //end date
    long end = endDate.toEpochDay();
    System.out.println(start);

    long randomEpochDay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().longs(start, end).findAny().getAsLong();
    System.out.println(LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomEpochDay)); // random date between the range
```

Comment: Why not use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(start, end)` instead of creating a stream?

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this

```
    long random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
    Date date = new Date(random);
```